# Subclass of GestureRecognizer does not work

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to subclass gesture recognizer to detect touch down , and not touch up .
The subclassing is working , only when i don't put this row to enable scrolling :

```
[touchDown requireGestureRecognizerToFail:scroller.panGestureRecognizer];
```

the subclass implementation :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible)
    {
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized;
    }
}
```

problem is , that i need that row ,otherwise the scroller will not move..

implementation :

```
 TouchDownGestureRecognizer *touchDown = [[TouchDownGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouchDown:)];
    [scroller addGestureRecognizer:touchDown];
    [touchDown requireGestureRecognizerToFail:scroller.panGestureRecognizer];//not work with it.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution to enable scroller :

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
     return YES;
}
```